# NSURLSession cancelling dataTask sometimes with error message Task finished with error - code: -999

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlsession

I am uploading png **Images->Base64->jsonData** in `URLRequest.httpBody` size around **6MB**. I am using a static `NSURLSession` with default Configuration and uploading using dataTask on urlsession. Sometimes its successfully uploaded to server sometimes its not and getting below error and nothing is printing at server side. I am not making parallel calls. We are using SSL pinning and handling authentication challenges proper so no SSL authentication error.
iOS device 11.3 and XCode 10 we are using.

**Task <58BF437E-7388-4AE4-B676-2485A57CB0CD>.<10> finished with error - code: -999**

```
private lazy var configuration: URLSessionConfiguration = {
        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(120)
        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = TimeInterval(120)
        return configuration
    }()
private lazy var urlSession = URLSession(configuration: URLSessionConfiguration.default, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)

func invokeService(methodName : String, collectionName: String, queryDictionary: [String:AnyObject]! = nil, httpMethod: String! = nil) {
        // Set up the URL request
        let baseUrl: String = WebServiceConstants.hostUrl.qaUrl + "/\(collectionName)" + "/\(methodName)"
       // let baseUrl: String = WebServiceConstants.hostUrl.demoUrl + "/\(collectionName)" + "/\(methodName)"
      // let baseUrl: String = WebServiceConstants.hostUrl.prod_Url + "/\(collectionName)" + "/\(methodName)"


        guard let url = URL(string: baseUrl) else {
            return
        }
        var urlRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
        // set up the session
//        let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
//        configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = TimeInterval(120)
//        configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = TimeInterval(120)
//
//        let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration, delegate: self, delegateQueue: nil)
        urlRequest.httpMethod = httpMethod
        do {
            urlRequest.httpBody = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: queryDictionary, options: []) // pass dictionary to nsdata object and set it as request body
        }
        catch _ {
        }

            urlRequest.setValue(WebServiceConstants.HTTPStrings.contentTypeJSON, forHTTPHeaderField: WebServiceConstants.HTTPStrings.contentTypeHeader)


       // print(queryDictionary)
        if AppController.sharedInstance.isAlreadyLogin() && (KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultKeys.authorizationHeaderValue) != nil) {
            let authorizationHeaderValue = WebServiceConstants.HTTPStrings.authorizationHeaderValue + KeychainWrapper.standard.string(forKey: Constants.UserDefaultKeys.authorizationHeaderValue)!
            urlRequest.setValue(authorizationHeaderValue, forHTTPHeaderField: WebServiceConstants.HTTPStrings.authorizationHeader)
        }

        let _ = urlSession.dataTask(with: urlRequest, completionHandler: { [unowned self]
            (data, response, error)   in

            //print(response)
            if error != nil {

                if error?._code == NSURLErrorTimedOut {
                   // print(error?.localizedDescription)
                    let userInfo = [
                        NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: BWLocalizer.sharedInstance.localizedStringForKey(key:"App_Timeout_Message")
                    ]
                    let errorTemp = NSError(domain:"", code:-1001, userInfo:userInfo)
                    self.delegate?.didFailWithError(errorObject: errorTemp)
                } else if error?._code == NSURLErrorNotConnectedToInternet {
                    let userInfo = [
                        NSLocalizedDescriptionKey: BWLocalizer.sharedInstance.localizedStringForKey(key:"Internet_Not_Available")
                    ]
                    let errorTemp = NSError(domain:"", code:-1001, userInfo:userInfo)
                    self.delegate?.didFailWithError(errorObject: errorTemp)
                }
               else  if error?._code == NSURLErrorCancelled {
                    // canceled
                  print("Request is cancelled") // Control reaches here on Finished with Error code = -999
                     self.delegate?.didFailWithError(errorObject: error!)

                }
                else {
                    self.delegate?.didFailWithError(errorObject: error!)
                }

            } else {

                do {

                    if let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: .allowFragments) as? [String: Any]
                    {
                        self.delegate?.didReceiveResponse(responseObject: json as AnyObject)
                        //Implement your logic
                        print(json)
                    }

                } catch {
                    self.delegate?.didFailWithError(errorObject: error)

                }
            }

        }).resume()


    }
```

***Added SSL Certificate pinning code ***

```
extension WebserviceHandler : URLSessionDelegate {
    func urlSession(_ session: URLSession, didReceive challenge: URLAuthenticationChallenge, completionHandler: @escaping (URLSession.AuthChallengeDisposition, URLCredential?) -> Void) {

        guard let trust = challenge.protectionSpace.serverTrust else {
            completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
            return
        }
        let credential = URLCredential(trust: trust)
        let pinner = setupCertificatePinner() // adding CertificateHash

        if (!pinner.validateCertificateTrustChain(trust)) {
            challenge.sender?.cancel(challenge)

        }

        if (pinner.validateTrustPublicKeys(trust)) {
            completionHandler(.useCredential, credential)

      }
            else {
            completionHandler(.cancelAuthenticationChallenge, nil)
            let popUp = UIAlertController(title: "", message: BWLocalizer.sharedInstance.localizedStringForKey(key:"Certificate_Pining_Fail_Message"), preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
            popUp.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: {alertAction in popUp.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)}))
            popUp.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: BWLocalizer.sharedInstance.localizedStringForKey(key:"Action_Go"), style: UIAlertAction.Style.default, handler: { action in
                let urlToOpenAppStorepage = URL(string: WebServiceConstants.hostUrl.appstore_url)
                let objApp = UIApplication.shared
                objApp.openURL(urlToOpenAppStorepage!)

            }))
            UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(popUp, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
   }

}

func setupCertificatePinner() -> CertificatePinner {
//      let baseUrl: String = WebServiceConstants.hostUrl.dev_URL

        let baseUrl: String = WebServiceConstants.hostUrl.qaUrl
//      let baseUrl: String = WebServiceConstants.hostUrl.demoUrl
         // let baseUrl: String = WebServiceConstants.hostUrl.prod_Url
        let pinner = CertificatePinner(baseUrl)

        /*

         You will see something like this:

         being challanged! for www.google.co.nz
         hash order is usually most specific to least, so the first one is your domain, the last is the root CA
         Production
         hash: 8U/k3RvTcMVSafJeS9NGpY4KDFdTLwpQ/GUc+lmPH/s=
         hash: 4vkhpuZeIkPQ+6k0lXGi7ywkVNV55LhVgU0GaWWMOdk=
         hash: jZzMXbxSnIsuAiEBqDZulZ/wCrrpW9bRLMZ6QYxs0Gk=
         hash: uthKDtpuYHgn+wRsokVptSysyqBzmr4RP86mOC703bg=
         you might need to change the has below to be the second one in the list for the code to pass

         QA
         hash: LX6ZGwP3Uii+KCZxDxDWlDWijvNI6K/t2906cUzKYM4=
         hash: 4vkhpuZeIkPQ+6k0lXGi7ywkVNV55LhVgU0GaWWMOdk=
         hash: jZzMXbxSnIsuAiEBqDZulZ/wCrrpW9bRLMZ6QYxs0Gk=
        */

        pinner.debugMode = true
        pinner.addCertificateHash(WebServiceConstants.HTTPStrings.hashKey)

        return pinner
    }
```

**Using pinning library : https://github.com/nicwise/certificatepinner**

Comment: could `urlSession` be dealloced? -999 means cancelled which it usually is that or SSL error..

Comment: UrlSession is in singleton class and there is no ssl error.

Comment: it is okay to put 6 mb data httpBody ? what is the size limit of httpBody ?

Comment: That is a server configuration.. Does it always fail or sometimes?

Comment: Show us any delegate methods (especially the one you're using for pinning).

Comment: The reason I ask that is that the most common cause of weirdness in code that uses delegate methods is calling the callback only some of the time, rather than every single time the delegate method gets called.  And the second most common cause is doing the wrong thing when presented with authentication challenge protection spaces that you aren't expecting.  (You should usually request default handling for anything that you aren't explicitly trying to handle.)

Comment: @dgatwood added ssl pinning code please review. Thanks

Comment: @Aris it fails sometimes but most of the times in case of image upload in dataTask, we have a plan for code improvement in future but before we need to solve this image upload cancellation issue. its in high priority, I am not getting any clue why its happening.

Answer (score 2):

I see several bugs in that code.

- The very first line in your authentication handler is going to cause failures if you're behind an authenticated proxy.

  It will also fail if the server wants any sort of HTTP auth password or OAuth credential.

  It will also fail in a number of other situations.

  You should never cancel an authentication request unless the request is actually bad in some way.  Canceling the authentication request also prevents the operating system from handling it transparently for you if you can.  The only situation where you should cancel an authentication request is if you check a cert or whatever and it is actually **invalid**.  Otherwise, you should generally trust the OS to do the right thing by default when you request external handling.

  So use default handling unless the authentication method is server trust.
- The code does not check the authentication method at all.  You should not be doing *any* checks unless the authentication method is server trust, for all of the reasons listed above.  If it is anything else, use default handling.  Always.
- The next if statement has two problems:

  - It provides a new state for the authentication request without returning.  This means you can call the completion handler afterwards, which could cause crashes and other misbehavior.
  - It is calling methods on the challenge sender that are intended to affect behavior.  That's how you used to do it with `NSURLConnection`, but you should *never* call any methods on the challenge sender (other than possibly to see if it is an object of your own creation, if you are using custom `NSURLProtocol` classes) with NSURLSession, because it can cause all sorts of problems, up to and including crashes.  (See the giant warning in the documentation for [NSURLAuthenticationChallenge's `-sender` method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurlauthenticationchallenge/1407533-sender?language=objc), or, for that matter, the two paragraphs before that warning.)
- I'm not entirely sure I trust the pinning code, either.  It looks like it passes if any key within the chain of trust is a trusted key, whereas typically pinning requires that the *last* (leaf) key in the chain of trust be a trusted key.
- The security advice in that pinning code is also dubious.  You probably shouldn't be pinning to a certificate, but rather to the **key inside** the certificate.  Pinning the leaf cert's key is entirely appropriate, and is really the only appropriate choice, because it is typically the only one whose key is actually under your direct control.  If you reissue the cert, that's no big deal, because you should be reissuing with the same key as before, unless your key has been compromised in some way.

  Alternatively, you can add a trust layer if you want, but this either requires running your own custom root (which would require changing the validateCertificateTrustChain method to add your custom root cert while validating the chain of trust) or convincing a CA to sell you a cert that can sign other certs, which costs $$$$.  Neither of these options seems very practical.

  Those issues make me a little bit concerned about the library as a whole, but I don't have time to audit it.  You should probably ask around and see if anybody has done a thorough audit of the library in question, as it is notoriously easy to make mistakes when writing code that works with TLS keys, and I'd hate to see you run into security problems later.

After you fix all of the bugs listed above, if you're still having problems, come back and ask another question with updated code.  Also, please also ask the code pinning project in question to fix their code snippets, as they seem to contain the same bugs.  :-)  Thanks.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed valuable suggestion let me review and implement them. I think we are pinning public key hash instead of cert, have to check with web team.